# Django use a context_processors.py with settings in Separate Settings Files

Tags: django

I use a context_processors.py based on this example: 
https://hackernoon.com/5-ways-to-make-django-admin-safer-eb7753698ac8

to Visually distinguish environments between local / internal / prod

Ex:

```
def from_settings(request):
    return {
        'ENVIRONMENT_NAME': settings.ENVIRONMENT_NAME,
        'ENVIRONMENT_COLOR': settings.ENVIRONMENT_COLOR,
    }
```

Like that I can use this variable in my template for example here in the admin page

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
    body:before {
        display: block;
        line-height: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: white;
        content: "{{ ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}";
        background-color: {{ ENVIRONMENT_COLOR }};
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

BUt I also introduce :  multiple settings file in order to separate my configuration

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html

Problem now I am no more able to display a variable in my template based on the settings file:
can you explain me or give me an example about context_processors based on several settings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: inside your `context_processor` file, import the concerned setting file, `if` `else` DEBUG can help you decide dev and prod

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
No need to if-else debug by doing like that the setting's file used is loaded

```
# app/context_processors.py
from django.conf import settings

import os


def from_settings(request):
    for name in dir(settings):
        environmentName = getattr(settings, 'ENVIRONMENT_NAME')
        environmentColor = getattr(settings, 'ENVIRONMENT_COLOR')
    return {
        'ENVIRONMENT_NAME': environmentName,
        'ENVIRONMENT_COLOR': environmentColor,
    }
```